# AWS Glue Initialise an empty Dynamic Frame

Tags: aws-glue

Is it possible in AWS Glue to initalise a fully empty Dynamic Frame?

My current approach is this but seems cumbersome:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Sesh').getOrCreate()
dfe = spark.createDataFrame([], StructType([]))

empty = DynamicFrame.fromDF(dfe, glueContext, 'empty')
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Empty RDD using:
EmptyRDD = spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD()

Add schema information for the empty RDD :
df_Existing_Data = spark.createDataFrame(emptyRDD, Schema Information)